# Foreach datatable does not get the last row

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Windows console application. In this windows console project, I will send an email.

It confuses me so much, because I can't get the last row to send an email when I execute it from an .exe file - but if I am debugging from Visual Studio it works.

I have already made sure that all the .dlls that I created are `Copy Local = True`. But still it does not work.

This is my code:

static void Main(string[] args)
        {

```cs
        DataSet dtPending = db.GetDataSet("GET_REMINDER_BACKDATE", CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        DataTable ds = dtPending.Tables[0];

        System.Console.WriteLine("Start looking pending approval ....");
        System.Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Rows)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("  Process {0} ..", row["DestinationName"].ToString());

                db.AddParameter("RequestID", row["RequestID"].ToString());
                db.AddParameter("ServerUri", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MIS_url"]);
                DataSet result = db.GetDataSet("GET_EMAIL_DATA_REMINDER", CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                DataTable datas = result.Tables[0];

                foreach (DataRow data in datas.Rows)
                {                      Mail.Send(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailSender"], row["DestinationEmail"].ToString(), "", data["EmailSubject"].ToString(), data["EmailContent"].ToString());
                }
                System.Console.WriteLine("  Insert to pending approval log");
                InserReminderBackdateLog(Guid.Parse(row["RequestID"].ToString()), row["RefferenceNo"].ToString(), row["EmployeeID"].ToString(), row["SBU"].ToString(), "1");
                System.Console.WriteLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //do nothing
                System.Console.WriteLine("  Error : {0}", ex.Message);
            }
        }
        System.Console.WriteLine("Finish ....");
        //System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Is this because of the `foreach` or the application itself? I can't find my mistake in the code.

Comment: Have you used the debugger and stepped through your loop?

Comment: Could you take out the `try`/`catch (Exception ex)` and see how it runs?

Comment: at a guess either ds.Rows is one smaller than you are expecting in which case you shouldn't see the Console.WriteLine's *or* if they are there but the email isn't sent then datas.Rows is empty for the last (one of?) the datasets.  Add a "System.Console.WriteLine("datas.Rows Count = {0}", datas.Rows.Count);" after = result.Tables[0]; and see what it is - is it ever less than you expect?

Answer (score 0):

try this:
instead of using datatable, use

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet(yourSqlCommandHere);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.Fill(ds);
```

replace your foreach into

```
foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    //Your code here.
}
```